# How to position Toolbar below a Map Fragment?

Tags: android, layout

I am making a Layout where I need to position a Toolbar below a Map Fragment. Well it may hear easy but from my small knowledge I hit upon a tricky problem.
Well I hv achieved how to get the toolbar below the fragment body but I hit on some problems:

1. When using Linear Layout, I split both the components using weights which was perfect as i needed it but couldnt get the Toolbar to the bottom of the Fragment.
2. While using Relative Layout, I was able to bring the toolbar below the fragment but since the map is big, i couldnt adjust the height of the map and the toolbar goes out of bounds.

What i need is the combined effect of weights from the LinearLayout and the 'android:Layout_below' effect from the Relative Layout.

I will post my code here:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/map1"
            />


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map1"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"


            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My toolbar is in a separate Layout 'app_bar'

Answer (score 0):

The Toolbar is just like any View, and can be placed wherever you want.  This is a big difference between it, and the ActionBar.

Just place the  element wherever you would like inside your layout.

In your case, don't place the Toolbar relative to the fragment, but relative to the parent (RelativeLayout) then you can control it's placement/size independent of your fragment (which you can then place relative to your Toolbar if you want that control)

Comment: Well I know that but I want a responsive Map Fragment which will adjust according to the screen size. The weights does it perfectly in linearlayout but i cant use weights in relativelayouts. So i m stuck in the part where the fragment stretches beyond the screen if i use wrap content and also i dont want a fixed size of the fragment. Isnt there any way to use effects like weights in the relative layout?

Comment: Sir, I hv tried it in many ways keeping your suggestion in mind, but the map is still overflowing the screen. could you please post a sample.

Comment: The other guys answer is correct.  You should be able to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"// or whatever...
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map1"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"


        />
```